# WINUI 3.0 или WPF (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

нужна помощь, вопрос скорее философский.
Необходимо создать приложение для работы (по типу менеджера устройств):

Примерно 3000-5000 устройств, разбитых по группам и подгруппам
Будет список групп, кастомный список устройств, разделенных по подгруппам
Работа с SQL, запросы SNMP, вывод подробной информации об устройстве.

Я проверил и в WinUi и в WPF, все что мне нужно работает.
Но, конечная папка проекта WPF занимает 10Мб, даже упакованный как ClickOnce тоже также,
а, конечный msix файл установки в WinUi занимает 70Мб, это конечно не много по современным меркам, но по старой привычке расточительно, так как там все файлы зависимостей.

Вопрос:
Стоит ли сейчас заморачиваться, и делать под WinUi, если да, то почему, какие преимущества?
Или лучше WPF?
Работа только с Windows 10-11!

Comment: Вкусовщина )) если можно так сказать , однако я работала с проектами на Wpf больше, выбрала бы его , простой, да и уроков любых много. по WinUi куда меньше инфы

Comment: Windows App SDK сыроват, и если вы пишете приложение, которое требует критической стабильности, то берите WPF. WinUI 3 стоит еще годик-два подождать прежде чем начать использовать, пока что, как практика показывает, он не готов к полноценному проду. Например, у меня есть клиент, который не может запустить WinUI 3 приложение совсем, нивкакую не стартует, ошибка внутри самого WinUI 3. Если работа только с 10-11, можете попробовать UWP. Конечно, если вы готовы бодаться с глюками WinAppSDK, и у вас есть время и настроение для этого, то берите его, он не страшный.